# This Riley Riddle is a Mess

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is hypocrisy,
>   My infix is before,
>   My suffix lasts for seven years,
>   My whole from which you pour.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are a:

> **CANTEEN**

*My prefix is hypocrisy,*

> **CANT** is a synonym for 'hypocrisy'.

*My infix is before,*

> **ANTE** means 'before' (as in 'ante meridiem', the hours before noon).

*My suffix lasts for seven years,*

> Your **TEEN** years last for seven years, from age 13 until 19.

*My whole from which you pour.*

> A *canteen* is a type of drinks container.

As for the title:

> A *canteen* can also be a place to eat communally, much like a *mess* on a ship or in the military...

I also like that:

> This riddle could be considered 'a mess' in that there is a *lot* of overlap between the three clued components, rather than them fitting tidily one after the other nose-to-tail. The title is not only a synonym of the answer but self-descriptive too!

Comment: The word which you describe, in the sense provided in the title, is a loan word from Chinese.